# database scheme for new user message

Tags: php, mysql

i wanted to know a good database scheme for a message that a new user see after he/she register and then after login he/she see that message like it would tell welcome to website . make friends etc .like the pic below

[image]

like every user who is new to website would see this message and then when user clicks on it then next time he/she login would not see it . do i have to maintain a database record for each n every user ? i m confused a bit . any other way i dnt knw ?

Comment: Could be a simple flag in the user record

Comment: yes does it means i have to do it via database ? or any other way out that i am unaware of

Comment: Depends on how persistent you want it to be.

Comment: no i dnt know how to do it , i thought of the simple flag method . but this way each user would have one , is there a possible method other then this

Comment: Depends on how persistent you want it to be. – Petra 2 mins ago edit

Comment: You can create a table with messages by user. If the message is processed, it's deleted from that table. If not, it's still there and is displayed. Job done. Index by user-id. Also if you add a time-stamp you can delete non-used ones after some logical time, e.g. 3 month or so. They are just rotting in there and can be deleted (or compressed like you didn't do this and this and this so far bla bla bla).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do for example, if you already have a table with user info in it. I assume you have because you are showing a avatar of the user.

Add a column called 'introduction'. And give it a 0 if a user hasn't clicked on introducing itself and after they've introduced it will change to a 1. So You do a query everytime you possibly want to show this message to check if the 'introduction' column has a 1 or 0 for that particular user.

Comment: thats the only way thought of can there be any more other way that i am unaware of

Comment: You can maybe do something with cookies/sessions. But that's easy to manipulate and they are likely to expire. If you, as a webmaster, store the information, you are 100% sure it won't change if you don't let them to. I would seriously consider this option.